# Very old Groundhog Day time travel short story where a man travels back in time killing his parents

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, time-travel

I think it must have been in Analog or Asimov in the early 1980s (81, 82, 83).
It's a short story with only TWO characters: The prisoner and the psychiatrist.

A man is seeing the prison psychiatrist. During the session, he identifies the cruel treatment by his father as the root of all his problems. When back in his cell he time travels (this seems to be an innate ability he has - no explanation is given, as I remember) and kills his father.

The following day he is back with the psychiatrist and identifies his being brought up by a neglectful single-parent mother as the root of all his problems. Once again, back in his cell he travels back in time and kills her.

The following day he identifies a cruel carer at the orphanage he grew up in...

The story goes through a number of, *Groundhog Day* style loops and finishes with a clever dark twist.

After a number of loops - all the possible people who may have influenced him in a bad way killed it ends with him in the psychiatrist office thinking,

> 'maybe seeing this psychiatrist has caused me to be the way I am?!' - Leading the reader to believe he will travel back in time and kill the psychiatrist before their first meeting).

Comment: _"finishes with a clever dark twist"_ - can you remember what that twist was? If so could you [edit] it in?

Comment: Maybe the same story as this old unanswered question: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/27965/time-travel-story-where-an-imprisoned-psychopath-kills-people-from-his-past

Comment: Seems to be asked by the same user?

Comment: Yes, sorry, it was a long time ago and I thought I had posted the question on a different forum. Maybe an admin person could delete the old post?  I have added the twist and specified that it is a short story and only the two characters in it - thanks.

Comment: Why not log into your old account, and add those details? https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts tells you how to do that.

Comment: There's a Spider Robinson story like this. See my answer to [this other SFF question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/121127/looking-for-short-stories-differing-from-two-spider-robinson-collections-from/205469#205469). No psychiatrist, only the main character.

Comment: @Ric Millen  Some people at this site might consider a story published in the the early  1980s to be a new story, not a very old story.

Comment: see OP confirmation comment above

Comment: Yes M.A. - seems like yesterday - although it also feels like another lifetime...